# Why can I not render controls on this UserControl when I add them via Controls.Add?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

After some more investigation, I've discovered that the problem I'm having extends beyond Progress Bars. For some unknown reason, none of the controls that I add programatically, via the `Controls.Add();` method, actually render themselves.

I've already tried sending the progress bar to the front, and I've experimented the same thing using Text boxes instead, but none of the controls actually render.

```
class HealthHandler
{
    public static int healthVar = 100;
    public ProgressBar healthBar = new ProgressBar();
    public ProgressBar instantiateHealth(SceneControl associatedControl)
    {
        healthBar.Value = healthVar;
        healthBar.Location = new Point(500, 250);
        healthBar.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        healthBar.Visible = true;
        associatedControl.Controls.Add(healthBar);
        return healthBar;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this method on the UserControl I wish to put the Progress Bar on.

```
health.instantiateHealth(this);
```

I added a small debugging method so I could check to see if any Progress Bars existed on the UserControl, and lo and behold, one does. A seemingly invisible progress bar. I know it's on the form, but I can't see it, and I really don't know why. I've also experimented with text boxes, and they too, are instantiating but not rendering.

After some investigation on Google, the only solutions I found didn't tailor to my situation, mainly because one of them was a problem with programmatically created UserControls, which aren't how I created my UserControls, and the other involved labels for use with a panel, which doesn't work in my UserControls either.

Comment: is your usercontrol large enough to display something at 500, 250? remember that point is from the top left of the usercontrol, not from the form.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness. I've been moving recently so I'm kind of hit and miss in terms of internet connection. Regardless, my UserControls have a size of 1366 x 740, so they're definitely large enough, but with some further investigation I found out something much more serious. Apparently, this isn't just a problem with progress bars, but any control I add to a UserControl programatically. That might be much more useful for you.

Comment: is ti possible for you to post your solution somewhere? I was able to get the progress bar to display with exactly your code, so there must be a problem with some other aspect of it...

Comment: @DrewJordan. I assume that means the entire project? The problem is that it's split into three separate projects under the guidance of one of my instructors. I did mention that this project was for a competition, right? Anyway, I'm running on very slow internet now, due to my sudden move, so I have the solution uploading to mediafire as we speak, but of course, it's taking some time. EDIT: I have the link here: https://www.mediafire.com/?79un6x4heanp28y

Comment: maybe just your usercontrol... it's hard to say. If I use your exact code, with this the only code in the usercontrol class: `HealthHandler health = new HealthHandler();
            health.instantiateHealth(this);
            Size = new Size(800, 800);` it works fine. One thing: you *are* adding the usercontrol to the form, right?

Comment: You may be onto something there. The way I'm building this project, all UserControls are instantiated as soon as the program starts, so they're all there, initialized but not showing, although I'm 100% sure that I'm calling `associatedControl.Controls.Add(healthBar);`, whilst "associatedControl" is `this`, meaning that whatever control I call this method on, I can say `health.instantiateHealth(this);` just like you did.

Comment: right, you can do that... But make sure you're adding your *usercontrols* to your *form* in the same way, something like `Form1.Controls.Add(UserControl1);`

Comment: @DrewJordan Yup. They're already added onto the main form. I've noticed that the Progress Bar is appearing on the UserControl, but just behind the picture box that I've spread over the entire UserControl. Once again, I've already experimented with `healthBar.BringToFront();` but I'm calling that in the actual healthHandler class, and I'm not sure if I can specify to bring the health bar to the front of the UserControl because "healthBar" doesn't exist in the UserControl that I call `health.instantiateHealth(this);` on. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: ah, yeah, that's it! Looking at your project definitely helped. You're right, it's showing behind the picturebox. The best thing to do is set the image as the UserControl's `BackgroundImage` instead of using a picturebox. That way any controls will always show up on top of the image.

Comment: @DrewJordan I finally got this all sorted now, thanks to you. I didn't know that there was a `BackgroundImage` property.